# WYSIWYG Redactor not working in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, codeception, redactor

I am trying to test my webpage using Codeception and PhantomJS, and everything works great except one annoying thing. WYSIWYG Redactor is not loaded by PhantomJS and all other javascript is not executed at all. I tried to isolate the problem by creating a very simple webpage with just Redactor in it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="redactor/redactor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="redactor/redactor.css">
    <script>
        $(function()
        {
            $('#redactor').redactor();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="" id="redactor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I have this simple test script that I give to PhantomJS:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/redactor/', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Result in example.png should be simple webpage with Redactor loaded, but instead I got PhantomJS error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tags.length')
http://localhost/redactor/redactor/redactor.js:6928
```

So I tried to fix redactor by putting `if(tags === undefined) return;`, but there are like 3-4 these bugs, always with `undefined` problem. When I fixed all of them I get webpage where is just textarea, but no WYSIWYG. In browser its rendered fine (FF, Chrome, Opera, ...), but in PhantomJS its bugged.

What am I doing wrong? Have any of you encoutered same problem?

Comment: You may try updating to PhantomJS 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem with PhantomJS version 1.9.7.

Upgrading to 2.0.0 fixed it. I used Homebrew:

```
brew update
brew upgrade phantomjs
```

Comment: I am using npm and there is no working PhantomJS2 package now (two available, but none can be installed, it throws error), but manual upgrade worked, so marking your answer as ok and thanks! :)